# list.append() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, telebot

I'm trying to create a function that randomly selects 10 photos locally. After that, it sends this data array to the user in Telegram.

Here is a piece of my code.

```
def send_certificates(message):
    text = 'tex'
    # The path to the folder with photos
    path = 'D://PYTHON//PROGRAMM//TelegramBot//img//certificates'
    # Получаем список всех файлов в папке
    file_list = os.listdir(path)
    # We filter the list, leaving only files with the extension.jpg or .png (or other supported formats)
    photo_list = [file for file in file_list if file.endswith('.jpg') or file.endswith('.png')]
    # If there are less than 10 photos in the folder, we display a message about it
    if len(photo_list) < 10:
        print("There are not enough photos in the folder!")
    else:
        # Randomly select 10 photos from the list
        selected_photos = random.sample(photo_list, 10)
    medias = []
    # We print the names of the selected photos
    for num, png in enumerate(selected_photos):
        if num == 0:
            medias.append(InputMediaPhoto(media=png), caption=text)
        else:
            medias.append(InputMediaPhoto(media=png))
    bot.send_media_group(chat_id=message.chat.id, media=medias)
```

But I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PYTHON\PROGRAMM\TelegramBot\main.py", line 305, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "D:\PYTHON\PROGRAMM\TelegramBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1043, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "D:\PYTHON\PROGRAMM\TelegramBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1118, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "D:\PYTHON\PROGRAMM\TelegramBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1074, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "D:\PYTHON\PROGRAMM\TelegramBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 147, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "D:\PYTHON\PROGRAMM\TelegramBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 90, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\PYTHON\PROGRAMM\TelegramBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 6788, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
  File "D:\PYTHON\PROGRAMM\TelegramBot\main.py", line 299, in info
    send_certificates(message)
  File "D:\PYTHON\PROGRAMM\TelegramBot\main.py", line 205, in send_certificates
    medias.append(InputMediaPhoto(media=png), caption=text)
TypeError: list.append() takes no keyword arguments
```

Comment: The error stack trace shows the problem. You are calling the list `append` method on the `medias` list, and passing a keyword argument to append. Remove the keyword argument `caption`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing

```py
medias.append(InputMediaPhoto(media=png), caption=text)
```

you probably meant to do

```py
medias.append(InputMediaPhoto(media=png, caption=text))
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first part of your if/else statement:

```py
medias.append(InputMediaPhoto(media=png), caption=text)
```

you call `medias.append()` with the main argument `InputMediaPhoto(media=png)` and the keyword argument `caption=text`. While you didn't post the `__init__()` method for `InputMediaPhoto`, is it possible you meant to write `InputMediaPhoto(media=png, caption=text)`? This would pass the `media` and `caption` parameters to the `InputMediaPhoto` constructor, so your syntax should be:

```py
medias.append(InputMediaPhoto(media=png, caption=text))
```